# What does this line of bash script do?

Tags: bash

```
nohup tensorflow_model_server \
  --rest_api_port=8501 \
  --model_name=fashion_model \
  --model_base_path="${MODEL_DIR}" >server.log 2>&1
```

I saw this in tensorflow serving guide [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/tutorials/serving/rest_simple#start_running_tensorflow_serving). I want to know the meaning of `> server.log 2>&1`. I kind of know that it's about saving `stdout` to a file, and saving `stderr` to another file which I don't know what it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This redirection is meant to *also* write the `stderr` output into the server log.

When you use a redirection like

```
some command > file.txt
```

It only saves output written by the program to `stdout`, the standard output stream usually connected to the console.

Most programs, however, adhere to the good practice of writing error messages to a different output stream, `stderr`, which while also printed on the console, can be "catched" and redirected separately in order to ensure error messages don't get overlooked in "verbose" normal output of the program.

This can however also become a problem: if you only redirect the "normal" output of some lengthy (and thus usually unattended) compile process, e.g., into a file, warnings and errors will only be printed to the console. If now you later come back to inspect the results, you will have standard "everything ok" output in your log file, and seemingly uncorrelated error output in your console.

Therefore, it can be helpful to "also redirect" the error output to the file, so that all messages are "in context".

The mechanism here is to

- first redirect `stdout` to a file (the `command > file` part, which explicitly could be written as `command 1>file`, the `1` indicating the file descriptor of the `stdout` stream)
- redirect the `stderr` in a "merging" way to `stdout`, too (that is why the syntax is `2>&1`, the `&` meaning "copy" the file descriptor), well-knowing that the `stdout` is already redirected to a file.

A good place for further reading might be

- the [Bash reference manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html)
- the [Bash programming introduction How-To](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-3.html)

Comment: A good was to read `2>&1` is: redirect stderr (2) to where stdout (1) is **currently** going. Not currently is is currently going to the file, as we are processing left to right, we have already directed stdout to the file.